# Amazon Lex postContent error "Failed to decode Session attributes."

Tags: php, amazon-lex

I am attempting to connect my webpage to my Lex bot using postContent from the AWS SDK for PHP.

I set the credentials and arguments then attempt postContent. Here is the relevant code:

```
$credentials = new \Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

$args = array(
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'debug' => true,
    'credentials' => $credentials
);

$lex_client = new Aws\LexRuntimeService\LexRuntimeServiceClient($args);

$lex_response = $lex_client->postContent([
    'accept' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'botAlias' => 'XXXX',
    'botName' => 'XXXX',
    'contentType' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'inputStream' => $userInput,
    'requestAttributes' => "{}",
    'sessionAttributes' => "{}",
    'userId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
]);
```

This errors with:

> 'Error executing "PostContent" on "https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bot/XXXX/alias/XXXX/user/XXXXXXXXXX/content";
>
> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bot/XXXX/alias/XXXX/user/XXXXXXXXXX/content` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>   {"message":"Invalid Request: Failed to decode Session attributes. Session Attributes should be a Base64 encoded json map of String to String"}' (length=142)

I have attempted using all kinds of JSON strings, JSON encoded strings, and Base64 encoded strings in the sessionAttributes but I continue to get this same error.

Comment: Have you attempted to set Content-type as application/json ?

Comment: @ParrettApps Thanks for the suggestion, was worth a try, but: Error="Unsupported content type application/json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LexRuntimeService in the AWS SDK automatically JSON encodes **and** Base64 encodes the postContent array. By passing it a JSON string, the json encoding in the SDK will place double quotes around the `{}` making it `"{}"` and that causes the error.

So simply pass the `sessionAttributes` and `requestAttributes` as PHP arrays.

```
$lex_response = $lex_client->postContent([
    'accept' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'botAlias' => 'XXXX',
    'botName' => 'XXXX',
    'contentType' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'inputStream' => $userInput,
    'requestAttributes' => array(),
    'sessionAttributes' => array(),            // <---- PHP Array not JSON
    'userId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
]);
```